# Can't import CSV contacts to Google

Tags: gmail, csv, import

I have a csv list I would like to import to google. I downloaded the basic sample from google here it goes:
cat contacts.csv

```
Name,Given Name,Additional Name,Family Name,Yomi Name,Given Name Yomi,Additional Name Yomi,Family Name Yomi,Name Prefix,Name Suffix,Initials,Nickname,Short Name,Maiden Name,Birthday,Gender,Location,Billing Information,Directory Server,Mileage,Occupation,Hobby,Sensitivity,Priority,Subject,Notes,Language,Photo,Group Membership,E-mail 1 - Type,E-mail 1 - Value,Phone 1 - Type,Phone 1 - Value,Phone 2 - Type,Phone 2 - Value
A Name,A,,Name,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,* myContacts,* ,email@gmail.com,Mobile,+number,Versão antiga,+number
```

Then I have a list as:

```
name 1,email 1,49292304
name 2,email,3943984338
...
```

I crafted the following awk command:

```
awk -F "," {'sub("\r$", ""); print $1",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,," $2",",","$3","","'}  alunos.csv
```

It generated me a proper CSV which **seems** in accord with the sample google provided me but i have an error in import time. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try adding the header line to the resulting CSV?

Comment: That solved the issue!

Comment: @MartinHorský, Could you please write out the solution as well fro the sake of ana answer to question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the header line to the CSV.

```
awk -F "," 'BEGIN { print "Name,Given Name,Additional Name,Family Name,Yomi Name,Given Name Yomi,Additional Name Yomi,Family Name Yomi,Name Prefix,Name Suffix,Initials,Nickname,Short Name,Maiden Name,Birthday,Gender,Location,Billing Information,Directory Server,Mileage,Occupation,Hobby,Sensitivity,Priority,Subject,Notes,Language,Photo,Group Membership,E-mail 1 - Type,E-mail 1 - Value,Phone 1 - Type,Phone 1 - Value,Phone 2 - Type,Phone 2 - Value" } {'sub("\r$", ""); print $1",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,," $2",",","$3","","'}'  alunos.csv
```